# Consola en C se cierra después de escribir un valor y guardarlo en una variable

Tags: c, consola

me han dejado crear un programa que pregunte el nombre de un alumno, pregunte el nombre de 4 materias y por ultimo sus calificaciones de esas materias. El problema es que al introducir el valor de la segunda materia la consola se cierra y no se muestra ningún erro. Todo lo anterior funciona bastante bien, sin embargo al preguntarme por el valor de la primera materia e introducir un valor, el programa se cierra y no muestra ningún error, agradecería su ayuda.
¡Gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char Nombre[100];
    char materia1[100];
    char materia2[100];
    char materia3[100];
    char materia4[100];
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;

// Imprimir la solicitud para obtener el nombre del alumno
    printf("Escribe tu nombre completo:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", Nombre);


// Solicitar las nombres de las materias //


// Nombbre de la materia 1
    printf("Escribe el nombre de tu primera materia:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", materia1);
    
// Nombbre de la materia 2
    printf("Escribe el nombre de tu segunda materia:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", materia2);
    
// Nombbre de la materia 3
    printf("Escribe el nombre de tu tercera materia:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", materia3);
    
// Nombbre de la materia 4
    printf("Escribe el nombre de tu cuarta materia:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", materia4);
    
    
// Solicitar las calificaciones de las materias //


// Calificacion de la materia 1
    printf("Escribe tu calificacion de %s (1 - 10):\n", materia1);
    scanf("%i", a);

// Calificacion de la materia 2
    printf("Escribe tu calificacion de %s (1 - 10):\n", materia2);
    scanf("%i", b);

// Calificacion de la materia 3
    printf("Escribe tu calificacion de %s (1 - 10):\n", materia3);
    scanf("%i", c);

// Calificacion de la materia 4
    printf("Escribe tu calificacion de %s (1 - 10):\n", materia4);
    scanf("%i", d);


    e = a + b + c + d; // Suma de las 4 materias
    f = e / 4; // Suma total de las materias dividida entra las 4 materias para obtener promedio


// Imprimir el nombre y promedio del alumno
    printf("%c tus promedio es de: %i", Nombre, f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%i", a);
```

`scanf` necesita recibir **punteros**, ya que de otra forma le sería imposible copiar la entrada del usuario en las variables que le facilitas.

Dado que `a` no es un puntero no puedes pasarle ese valor directamente, necesitas obtener la dirección de memoria de dicha variable, y para eso tenemos el operador `&`:

```
scanf("%i", &a);
//          ^
```

Comment: Toda la razón, error de principiante.

¡Muchas gracias!